# Помощь по схеме базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Есть сайт где пользователь может задавать вопросы другим пользователям (одному или нескольким). У меня есть таблыцы: пользователи-`tb_users` и вопросы-`tb_question`, теперь как мне как мне хранить данные о том, какой пользователь каким-(ому) пользователям-(ю) задаёт вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В том виде в котором вы задали вопрос ответ будет следующим.

Вам нужна дополнительная таблица `tb_recipients` с двумя полями - `id_question` и `id_recipient` (foreign key к question и users соответственно).

Допустим, вам нужно вопросу с id = 18 дать видимость пользователям с id = 3, 4 и 5. В этом случае вы в таблицу `tb_recipients` вносите три записи: (18, 3), (18, 4) и (18, 5)

За кадром вы оставили вопрос. А сайт будет только сайтом, на котором каждый вопрос виден только ограниченному кругу лиц? Это каждый раз нужно будет указывать кому виден вопрос, неудобно.

А если нужно сразу пару десятков человек указать в получателях? В этом случае можно будет облегчить создание вопросов по шаблонам, указывая видимость не на базе отдельных пользователей, а на основе групп пользователей. (Тут большой простор для творчества).

И если вдруг вы задумаетесь добавить на сайте возможность задавать вопросы публичные, с видимостью "неограниченному кругу лиц" - то тоже нужно будет допиливать схему. Например, создать дополнительное поле на вопросе boolean поле `is_public`, чтобы понимать учитывать ли данные в таблице  `tb_recipients`.

> А, что если вместо id_user я буду добавлять username(varchar20). Это
>   никак не повлияет на производительность?

Так не делают. Принято в запросах на выборку делать INNER JOIN и получать имя пользователя. А в таблицах хранят int'товые идентификаторы. Join по int намного более производительная операция, чем join по строке.

Иногда (в высокопроизводительных системах) могут продублировать поле username, чтобы ещё больше выиграть в производительности некоторых операций. Но на вашем уровне понимания SQL лучше всего хранить данные в третьей нормальной форме, а когда уже научитесь - можете для общего развития почитать про денормализацию в highload'е.

Comment: А, что если вместо `id_user` я буду добавлять `username(varchar20)`. Это никак не повлияет на производительность?

Comment: @ruslan4742 дополнил ответ. Ещё как повлияет! В худшую сторону.